# issue abut multiple unique key

Tags: sql, key, unique

it`s code to create my table

```
CREATE TABLE tblfriend
(fk_UserID1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
 fk_UserID2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(fk_UserID1, fk_UserID2),
 UNIQUE(fk_UserID1, fk_UserID2),
 FOREIGN KEY(fk_UserID1) REFERENCES tbluser(UserID),
 FOREIGN KEY(fk_UserID2) REFERENCES tbluser(UserID)
);
```

must this unique multiple key not allowed buttom inserted record:

```
fk_UserID1 - fk_UserID2
     1     -      2
     2     -      1
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL,  MS SQL Server, etc..) which u r using.

Comment: `create unique index unique_friends on tblfriend (least(fk_userid1, fk_userid2), greatest(fk_userid1, fk_userid2));`